# Pipe input of a variable stored as a command string

Tags: bash, sed

How can I do this?

```
[root@ipaserver ~]# ls | sed 's/.*/"&"/'
"anaconda-ks.cfg"
"ca-agent.p12"
```

Like this?

```
[root@ipaserver ~]# !QUOTED
QUOTED="sed 's/.*/\"&\"/'"
[root@ipaserver ~]# echo $QUOTED
sed 's/.*/"&"/'
[root@ipaserver ~]# ls| $QUOTED
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I've tried all kinds of variations and nested echo command/process substitutions and eval. Is this possible to do for scripting purposes?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): `for f in *; do echo \"$f\"; done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
QUOTED='sed s/.*/"&"/'
ls | $QUOTED
```

Comment: +1 Power of quotes. I was thinking along the lines of `eval`, but this is good.

Comment: I tried this at first but was discouraged when I saw this:

$ echo $QUOTED
sed s/.*/"&"/

An absense of quotes around the expression is the ultimate sed sin normally. Why does that not matter here?

Comment: Nevermind, I realize now that the entire thing being quoted means that the inner expression is taken literally as it would be in a normal #sed 's/.*/"&"/' command. So obvious, yet not. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you have there works fine for me with the addition of an `eval`:

```
$ QUOTED="sed 's/.*/\"&\"/'"
$ echo $QUOTED
sed 's/.*/"&"/'
$ ls | eval $QUOTED
"file1"
"file2"
"file3"
"file4"
```

Comment: If you don't have complete control over what's in the command string, `eval` can have unexpected consequences. (And if you do have complete control, why bother storing it in a variable anyway?)

Comment: I want to use the variable in a script that has a lot of parsing commands that return values with spaces that I want to run loops against. If the values aren't quoted then it expands to something like "for i in 'this' 'has' 'spaces'..." instead of "for i in 'this has spaces'..."

Answer (score 1):

you want a shell alias here

```
alias QUOTED='sed "s/.*/\"&\"/"'
```

As you can see, the quoting gets a little tricky. Using a function is clearer

```
unalias QUOTED
QUOTED() { sed 's/.*/"&"/'; }
```

In both cases:

```
$ printf "%s\n" foo bar baz | QUOTED
"foo"
"bar"
"baz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the best way to handle this sort of thing is storing the command as an array:

```
sedcmd=(sed 's/.*/"&"/')
ls | "${sedcmd[@]}"
```

See [BashFAQ #50:I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more options and discussion.